# What active record association do I use in this scenario?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations, nested-attributes

Newbie to rails and having a hard time finding the right relationship to use.

I have an Account and a User model. I want to define their relationship through a Relationship model.

A user can own/moderate/subscribe to many accounts.
An account can have many owners/moderators/subscribers.
A relationship can be of type owner/moderator/subscriber.

I want to be able to create an account and a user at the same time through `accounts_controller.rb` (pseudo-code):

```
def new
    if signed_in?
        current_user.account.build
    else
        @account = Account.new
        @owner = Account.owner.build
    end
end

def create
    if signed_in?
        current_user.account.build
        current_user.save? redirect_to(current_user) ? render 'new'
    else
        if @account.save
            @user = Account.owner
            sign_in @user
            redirect_to @user
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
end
```

1. Where should `accepts_nested_attributes_for` go, in the User model or the Account model?  This makes a difference because I want to be able to create the user through the account, and not the account through the user.
2. Would this even work given that there's a relationships table? Can it be done with a has_many through? This is what's throwing me off. I have no idea how my models should look like.
3. I'm afraid my relationship design is flawed. Not sure if a User should only have one relationship to an Account (owner, **or** moderator, **or** subscriber) or multiple relationships with the same account (owner **and** subscriber **and** moderator).

Comment: Calling `Account.owner` implies that there is only *one* account and *one* owner in the entire app, which seems to conflict with the rest of your description.

Comment: Andrew, I appreciate the comment. Given this, what are my options for achieving my goal? I never anticipated my code to be correct. I was trying to give an idea of what I want in order to get help and arrive at my object.

Comment: This is a good question and I'd like to help but I haven't done a accepted_nested_attributes_for with a relationship table.  Another solution would be to back off from accepted_nested_attributes_for entirely and create a new form to collect the information and in the controller create the models based on that data.